# Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 error. When passing a function as a prop to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I passed the deleteImgfunc function from the insertFarmDiaryDetail component to the InsertFarmDiarySubPage component, which is a child component. The deleteImgfunc function is a function that receives parameters.

So, like my code, even though I created an interface and a value that receives parameters, a red warning line appears in v?.name and this warning message occurs.

Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3vgB.png)

How can I get rid of this warning? How do I fix my code?

this is my code

(insertFarmDiaryDetail.tsx)

```
const insertFarmDiaryDetail = () => {

const deleteImgfunc = useCallback((value) => {
}, []);

return (
<InsertFarmDiarySubPage
    deleteImgfunc={deleteImgfunc}
/>
)
}
```

(InsertFarmDiarySubPage.tsx)

```
interface IProps {
    deleteImgfunc?: () => void;
}

v = {
index: 0
name: "growthLength 1"
size: 22396
type: "image/jpeg"
uri: "hjk"
}

const InsertClass44 = forwardRef(({ deleteImgfunc }: IProps, ref: any): JSX.Element => {

    return (
<Pressable}
    onPress={() => deleteImgfunc?.(v?.name)}
>
</Pressable>    
    );


})
export default InsertClass44;
```

Comment: `deleteImgfunc?: () => void;` You defined the type as not taking arguments, which does not match the function you're passing

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh... how should i fix it?....

Comment: By defining the type properly - the type of `deleteImgfunc`

Answer (score 0):

check for
HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(): void {

}

if you are using $event, you shouldnt keep onResize empty.
e.g.onResize(e)